# How can I make this program smaller?

Tags: tips, python, optimization, tree-traversal

I am trying my hand at writing super small programs. I wrote a simple "tree" display program for showing a graphical representation of a folder hierarchy. I have made it small in all the ways I can think of. I was just wondering if you guys had more creative ways to "minify" it further. Here is the small version as well as a human-readable version.

```
import os,os.path as p
def w(c,d,s):
    a=os.listdir(c);s=s+'|';i=0
    for f in a:
        print s+'--'+f;j=p.join(c,f);
        if p.isdir(j):w(j,d+1,s[:-i==len(a)-1]+'  '*(d+1));i=i+1
def t(c):print c;w(c,0,'')
t(p.curdir)
```

That's a total of 236 bytes

```
import os

def treeWrap(curdir,depth,pipeStr):
    files = os.listdir(curdir)
    pipeStr = pipeStr + '|'
    for f in files:
        print pipeStr + '--' + f
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(curdir,f)):
            dir = os.path.join(curdir,f)
            if files.index(f) == (len(files)-1):
                treeWrap(dir,depth+1,pipeStr[:-1] + '  '*(depth+1))
            else:
                treeWrap(dir,depth+1,pipeStr + '  '*(depth+1))

def tree(curdir):
    print curdir
    treeWrap(curdir,0,'')

tree(os.path.curdir)
```

Oh, in addition, does anyone know how I can use the unicode ├,└,─ in this program? Whenever I use them they appear as garbage in the console and the idle interpreter.

Comment: A bunch of generic minifying python techniques are here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python

Comment: `p=os.path` is 3 characters shorter than `os.path as p`.

Comment: Probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I believe you got advised to try this here on Stack Overflow, but the person who suggested that wasn't entirely familiar with our FAQ. Each "question" here is expected to pose a game or challenge with a well defined winning criteria and enough flexibility to be *fun* for participants. This is not a site for general question (with the special exception of the "hints" questions).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with your minified version: `s[:-0]` gives you the empty string, not the complete string as you anticipate with `s[:-i==len(a)-1]`. To rectify this, you will need to either ignore preceding bars or calculate the a little more thoroughly. The shorter version would be to ignore preceding bars and not worry about passing spacing to further recursions. Since it permits the removal of several variables, I worked your code to do this

Your `tree` function is only called once, I removed it.

`s=s+'|'` and `i=i+1` can be collapsed into `s+='|'` and `i+=1`

`os.path as p` can become `p=os.path` (Thanks [James](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3974/james))

`p.join(c,f)` can become `c+'/'+f` (Thanks [beary605](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4303/beary605))

New version:

```
import os,p=os.path
def w(c,d):
    for f in os.listdir(c):
        print '  '*(d+1)+'|--'+f;j=c+'/'+f
        if p.isdir(j): w(j,d+1)
z=p.curdir;print z;w(p.curdir,0)
```

If you really wanted to go crazy, you can make put this all on one line and get it down to 143 bytes (on linux)

```
import os,p=os.path
def w(c,d):
 for f in os.listdir(c):print'  '*(d+1)+'|--'+f;j=c+'/'+f;w(j,d+1)if p.isdir(j)else 0
z=p.curdir;print z;w(z,0)
```

Comment: Remove unecessary whitespace (5chars), and also replace `p.join(c,f)` with `c+'/'+f` (4chars): `for f in os.listdir(c):print'  '*(d+1)+'|--'+f;j=c+'/'+f;w(j,d+1)if p.isdir(j)else 0`

Comment: @beary605 Will `c+'/'+f` yield the same result as `p.join(c,f)` on a windows box?

Comment: It will, does it not on Linux?

Comment: The docs say [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) uses [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.sep) which "is `'/'` for POSIX and `'\\'` for Windows".

Comment: It works in Windows. Windows is pretty lenient with their file paths.